# how to limit calculation to specific number

Tags: jquery, html

Input field are dynamic and will be added from PHP as user requirement.

The sum of multiple Input field has been calculating live and displaying in specific class.

Now, I want to `limit` the calculation to 100 or specific number. If calculation reaches 100, then how to `stop` or `disable` to fill data ?

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.m_add', function(){  
  var sum = 0;
  $(".m_add").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).html();
  });
  $(".total").html(sum);
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
table th{
  width:30%;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px; }

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7; }

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #0E539A; }

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #BCD4E6;
  color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Exam</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Second Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Third Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Final</th>
      <td class='total'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried? I don't see an attempt to limit the calculations

Comment: Hint: use input events. too late when you blur

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for hint. Is `input` event better and faster than `contenteditable ` ?

Comment: Not what I meant. Can use user input events on contenteditable also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check sum is less or equal to 100 and then add to total otherwise make input value empty

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.m_add', function(){  
  var sum = 0;
  $(".m_add").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).html();
  });
  if(sum<=100){
    $(".total").html(sum);
  } else{
    $(this).html('');
  }
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
table th{
  width:30%;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px; }

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7; }

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #0E539A; }

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #BCD4E6;
  color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Exam</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Second Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Third Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Final</th>
      <td class='total'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that way... user knows limit exceeded

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `if` condition on `sum` value:

```
if(sum <=100){
   $(".total").html(sum);
}
```

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.m_add', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".m_add").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).html();
  });
  if (sum <= 100) {
    $(".total").html(sum);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  width: 30%;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #0E539A;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #BCD4E6;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Exam</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Second Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Third Term Exam</th>
      <td class='m_add' contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Final</th>
      <td class='total'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does this "stop" or "disable" the input as the OP asked?

Comment: @j08691 it `stops` as OP says `stop` or `disable`. Fill `40` in all fields and it does not print `160` in HTML

Comment: There is no reason to downvote my answer and upvote your comment because it `stop` the value to be filled that is greater than `100` as OP says `stop` or `disable`, I choose to solve this by `stop` =

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to prevent someone from entering a value in one or more inputs when the total is 100, not just change the result.

Comment: @j08691 then OP should have mentioned `disable` and not `stop` or `disable`.

Comment: He *did* mention disable and I didn't upvote my own comment (which you can't even do) or downvote your answer.

Comment: Also not considering that user has no idea why nothing changed

Comment: @j08691 it does not make sense to disable. If we `disable` it then user cannot change the value and enable it again

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, Thanks for your answer, it works but I found adding blank value using `.html('')` would be more effective for user as @Bhushan answer.

Comment: Sure it does. You disable the empty inputs before the user can enter anything once the other inputs total 100. Change an existing input, un-disable the others.